# How do I get Customer Price Group, Business Central API 2.0

Tags: dynamics-business-central

How do I get Customer Price Group in Business Central?
I've looked through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/api-reference/v2.0/ several times without any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no default API available to retrieve the Customer Price Group.

You will have to create your own API by [extending Business Central](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/developer/devenv-dev-overview).